# Get a next row value from the table if first is null with filter conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get the next row value for a particular column if first row contains `NULL`?

Data looks like below;

**Table 1:**

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | BASD |
| 1 | KLJY |
| 2 | Brush |
| 2 | RISHI |
| 3 | Paint |

**Table 2 :**

| ID | ASSET_NUMBER | PRIMARY_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5478 | Y |
| 1 |  | NULL |
| 2 |  | Y |
| 2 | 8956 | NULL |
| 2 |  | N |
| 3 | 2547 | Y |
| 3 |  | NULL |

We need to get the combined result from Table 1 and Table 2 using LEFT JOIN where Table 2 `PRIMARY_FLAG` column value should be `Y` but if there is no value in the `ASSET_NUMBER` column for the `Y` PRIMARY_FLAG value then query should return next row where `ASSET_NUMBER` column should have a numeric value *(it should not be null or empty)*.

**OUTPUT:** *(expected result using table 1 join table 2)*

| ID | NAME | ASSET_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BASD | 5478 |
| 1 | KLJY | 5478 |
| 2 | Brush | 8956 |
| 2 | RISHI | 8956 |
| 3 | Paint | 2547 |

I've written a SQL query below using `LEFT JOIN`, however it's not producing the desired results and also the rows are multiplying by table1*table2;

```
SELECT
  t1.ID,
  t1.Name,
  t2.Asset_Number
FROM 
  Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1._ID = t2.ID and Primary_Flag = 'Y'
```

Please suggest the changes in the query to get the desired outcome.

Comment: When you say "next row" this implies an ordering of the rows which you have no column to support. Your example data only has a single row per `ID` where `PRIMARY_FLAG` is `NULL` and `ASSET_NUMBER` is not null - is this always going to be the case? That for an `ID` there will be no more than one possible row for `PRIMARY_FLAG='Y'` and one possible fallback row?

Comment: use outer apply perhaps. `select * from maintable m outer apply (select top 1 * from secondtable s where s.id = m.id order by case when asset_number <> '' then 1 else 0 end desc) s` or do you need some sort of data from the Y row specifically as well?

Comment: @MartinSmith @siggemannen I need a row which have a Primary Flag values as 'Y', but if Asset Number is null/empty for the 'Y' Primary Flag value then we need to pull the next non null asset number value which have Primary Flag as `NULL` or 'N'

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your data structure in that there is no guaranteed order of your rows. It's *possible* that they could come out of the tables like you've described, but it's also possible that they could come out in a different order.

Unless you address that, there would be no way to create a reliable range of rows between `PRIMARY_FLAG` = 'Y' and `PRIMARY_FLAG` = 'N'. For all we know, it's possible to have dozens of `NULL` rows between those two values.

However, With this in mind, here are two options. Both are unreliable since the order out of your tables aren't guaranteed -

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
    ID INT
  , NAME VARCHAR(12)
);

CREATE TABLE T2
(
    ID INT
  , ASSET_NUMBER INT
  , PRIMARY_FLAG CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO T1
VALUES
(1, 'BASD')
, (1, 'KLJY')
, (2, 'Brush')
, (2, 'RISHI')
, (3, 'Paint');

INSERT INTO T2
VALUES
(1, 5478, 'Y')
, (1, NULL, NULL)
, (2, NULL, 'Y')
, (2, 8956, NULL)
, (2, NULL, 'N')
, (3, 2547, 'Y')
, (3, NULL, NULL);
```

**Original query -**

```
SELECT t1.ID
     , t1.Name
     , t2.Asset_Number
FROM T1
    LEFT JOIN t2
        ON t1.ID = t2.ID
           AND Primary_Flag = 'Y';
```

| ID | Name | Asset_Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BASD | 5478 |
| 1 | KLJY | 5478 |
| 2 | Brush | *null* |
| 2 | RISHI | *null* |
| 3 | Paint | 2547 |

**Very next row if `ASSET_NUMBER` is `NULL` -**

```
SELECT t1.ID
     , t1.Name
     , X.ASSET_NUMBER
FROM t1
    OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT COALESCE(ASSET_NUMBER, LEAD(ASSET_NUMBER, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)) AS ASSET_NUMBER
         , PRIMARY_FLAG
    FROM T2
    WHERE t1.ID = ID
) AS X
WHERE X.PRIMARY_FLAG = 'Y';
```

| ID | Name | ASSET_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BASD | 5478 |
| 1 | KLJY | 5478 |
| 2 | Brush | 8956 |
| 2 | RISHI | 8956 |
| 3 | Paint | 2547 |

**First non-`NULL` value for a given ID after a `NULL` `ASSET_NUMBER` where `PRIMARY_FLAG` = 'Y' -**

```
WITH T2_
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS rn
         , *
    FROM T2
)
SELECT t1.ID
     , t1.Name
     , T3.ASSET_NUMBER
FROM T1
    OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1
           COALESCE(T3.asset_number, T4.ASSET_NUMBER) AS ASSET_NUMBER
    FROM T2_ AS T3
        OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
               ASSET_NUMBER
        FROM T2_ AS T4
        WHERE T3.ID = T4.ID
              AND T3.ASSET_NUMBER IS NULL
              AND T3.PRIMARY_FLAG = 'Y'
              AND T4.rn > T3.rn
        ORDER BY rn ASC
    ) AS T4
    WHERE T3.ID = t1.ID
    ORDER BY T3.rn
) AS T3;
```

| ID | Name | ASSET_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BASD | 5478 |
| 1 | KLJY | 5478 |
| 2 | Brush | 8956 |
| 2 | RISHI | 8956 |
| 3 | Paint | 2547 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KQxHBezM)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your data structure... But this is a repetition :)

```
with
  t1 as (
    select
      id, name
    from
      (VALUES
         (0, 'BASE'),
         (1, 'BASD'),
         (1, 'KLJY'),
         (2, 'Brush'),
         (2, 'RISHI'),
         (3, 'Paint')) as t(id, name)
  ),
  T2 as (
    select
      id, asset_number, primary_flag
    from
      (VALUES
         (1, 5478, 'Y'),
         (1, -1, NULL),
         (2, NULL, 'Y'),
         (2, 8956, NULL),
         (2, NULL, 'N'),
         (3, 2547, 'Y'),
         (3, NULL, NULL) ) as t(id, asset_number, primary_flag)
  ),
  t3 as (
    select
      t1.*,
      t2.asset_number,
      row_number() over(partition by t1.id, t1.name
                        order by t2.primary_flag) rn
    from
      t1
    left join (
      select
        id, asset_number,
        coalesce(primary_flag, 'Z') primary_flag
      from t2
      where
        asset_number is not null and
        (primary_flag is null or
         primary_flag = 'Y')
    ) t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
  )
select *
from t3
where rn = 1
;
```

```
+----+-------+--------------+----+
| id | name  | asset_number | rn |
+----+-------+--------------+----+
|  0 | BASE  | null         |  1 |
|  1 | BASD  | 5478         |  1 |
|  1 | KLJY  | 5478         |  1 |
|  2 | Brush | 8956         |  1 |
|  2 | RISHI | 8956         |  1 |
|  3 | Paint | 2547         |  1 |
+----+-------+--------------+----+
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G5Z-Ztqc)